# a sense or senses

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have been facing a difficulty understanding the usage between singular or plural forms in situations like this:

*I give them a book.*

*I give them books.*

If my understanding is right, the first sentence means I give a group of people just ONE book, while the second means I give a group of people more than one book. However, the following sentence sounds just alright to me, and I have seen some similar uses thrown around on the Internet.

*The activity helps them develop a keener sense of body awareness.*

My question is, if this is grammatically correct, why does it use "a sense of" while the activity should have helped each of them develop a keener sense, which sums up to more than one sense? Or should it be:

*The activity helps them develop keener senses of body awareness.*

Comment: Individual senses (such as sight or smell) only take the singular form: *Their sense of smell was unaffected*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one sense of body awareness. You can't possibly say,

> Their *senses* of touch *have* improved